# What is the code to the safe?

Tags: home

After falling asleep, and waking up, I think I'm stuck in Home. I've searched around the house everywhere I can think of, and interacted with everything I found. But, I still  can't leave the house through the front or back door, or enter the basement. I get messages about needing answers, and making sure I'm clear.

The only thing that I've found left in the house is a safe requiring an eight digit code to open. I've found absolutely nothing that I can remember that would give a hint as to this code. Is the code to the safe something obvious, or something I overlooked, or is there something else in the house that I overlooked that isn't allowing me to leave?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is

> 4R3UHER3

If you ordered the special edition and got the physical items or go to [this page here](http://www.homehorror.com/wtf/), you can get the code out of the file names.

Answer (score 3):

If you bought the Steam version, the code (same as given as answer above) is given to you within the pdf-manual that comes along with the game. It's a bit hidden but I'm sure you will see it. 
Can't find the pdf? View the game in Steam store, scroll down, and in the right column you will se the link "View the manual".

Answer (score 1):

The key to the basement is in the attic. You can see the opening by looking up on the top floor.